# Windows Azure: AD app for external access throws error on token issue

Tags: windows, azure, active-directory

I am trying to build an AzureAD access app. I have to enable this app for external tenants. I have enabled external access on this app and it is configured to use the Graph API also. I have tested the app in the tenant in which it was created and everything(auth+ graph api access) works. Now here is the flow for the external tenant

- I take the external tenant user to the grant consent URL of my app, the user(who is an admin of the external tenant) grants the access and i get the correct response
- Now i want to get the authorization token for this user, so i take the user through the normal Oauth process via

  ```
  https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize
  ```

followed by

```
    https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/token/
```

At this point Azure throws the following error

```
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"AADSTS50000: There was an error issuing a 
token. AADSTS65005: No permission to access \u0027https://graph.windows.net\u0027 
resource is configured for \u0027d2037ff7-24e4-4cac-8e5e-16e370b36238\u0027 application, 
or it is expired or revoked.\r\nTrace ID: 472aa92f-35a2-4ed9-ab07-
12488cc9e6f5\r\nCorrelation ID: b163dde5-eac5-4c82-99ad-0e1100487cb9\r\nTimestamp: 2013-
09-23 05:28:41Z","error_codes":[50000,65005],"timestamp":"2013-09-23 
05:28:41Z","trace_id":"472aa92f-35a2-4ed9-ab07-12488cc9e6f5","correlation_id":"b163dde5- 
eac5-4c82-99ad-0e1100487cb9"}
```

Why this error even when the app has been granted access. I tried to lookup the `STS` errors 
but found no explanation. Any ideas?

**[update]**

SAML process continues to work for the external tenant however i.e I can use the app for SAML(SSO) login for this external tenant. The problem only seems to be coming for getting access to the graph API.

Comment: Did you find the answer? I get the same error...

Comment: @Stefan I tried this about 3 months back and the problem was still there. Not sure about the current status. I am pretty much sure that it was some bug in AzureAD

Comment: +1  I'm getting the same error in /authorize endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `&prompt=consent` or `&prompt=admin_consent` to the full `authorize` URL to re-request the user consent. My experience has been that the consent will be randomly revoked (maybe a bug) and will not ever be automatically re-requested (definitely a bug).

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out how to manually revoke my previously given consent so that I can test error handling in apps...

Comment: I'm a bit late to this party, but the best place I've found for revoking consent is to go to https://myapps.microsoft.com and remove the application you're testing from your account there. After that, you should be re-prompted for consent.

Comment: @slavikko: Yeah, that works in theory. However, at least my account lists apps with consent and only options for such app are "Get info" and "Report a problem". There's no action "Remove" or "Revoke consent".

Comment: yes, this doesn't work if the application is in your tenant, as that can't be removed (if it's from another party it is removable from there). There was some powershell magic available to revoke the consent for applications that originate from your AAD, but I can't seem to find the info on that it right now.